# How to prove a single-point correlation function equal to zero?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, symmetry, correlation-functions

A short question, when I am studying QFT-P&S's book, try to use completeness relation (7.2) to expand the two-point correlation function: $$\langle\Omega|\hat T{\phi(x)\phi(y)}|\Omega\rangle\tag{7.3}$$ in to (7.3), P&S say:

> the term  $\langle\Omega|\phi(x)|\Omega\rangle$ & $\langle\Omega| \phi(y)|\Omega\rangle$(or for spin half field: $\langle\Omega|\psi(x)|\Omega\rangle$ & $\langle\Omega|\bar \psi(y)|\Omega\rangle$) are usually zero by symmetry; for higher-spin field it's zero by Lorentz invariance.

My question is, know how to prove this claim? (both for $\phi$ and $\psi$)

This is the original P&S book: (P. 212)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the cases that Peskin & Schroeder are referring to, both the action and the path-integral measure have the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ global symmetry $ \phi(x) \mapsto -\phi(x).$

This means that the full quantum theory has that symmetry, and hence so do correlation functions. Therefore
$$\left<\Omega\middle\vert \phi(x) \middle\vert\Omega\right> = 0,$$
since it is odd under that $\mathbb{Z}_2$, assuming that the vacuum does not break the symmetry.

Comment: then for $\langle\Omega|\psi(x)|\Omega\rangle$ & $\langle\Omega|\bar \psi(y)|\Omega\rangle$ is the same reason?

Comment: @aFishinDiracSea yes

Comment: But looks like Peskin & Schroeder say “for higher-spin field it's zero by Lorentz invariance.” It looks like implie us use Lorentz invariance to derive $=0$ for non-zero spin field.

Comment: @aFishinDiracSea [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/158772/142398) phys.SE answer shows the claim by Lorentz invariance. This is the formally correct way to do it, if you assume that $\bar{\psi}(x)$ is independent of $\psi(x)$. But if you relate them by complex conjugation (decorated appropriately with $\gamma$ matrices and transposition) my answer holds.

Comment: thanks a lot! is very helpfull!

Answer (score 1):

Let us mention for completeness that even if there is no symmetry to ensure the vanishing of the 1-point functions $\langle\phi\rangle$, the vanishing $\langle\phi\rangle=0$ is often imposed as a renormalization condition, cf. e.g. Ref. 1 and my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/544628/2451).

References:

1. M. Srednicki, *QFT,* 2007; eq. (9.2). A prepublication draft PDF file is available [here](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emark/qft.html).